# iTunes connect - TestFlight - Console Error on Selecting Build for Test Group

Tags: app-store-connect, testflight

I am trying to setup TestFlight for a new app.

I have uploaded a build, setup Test Information and created a new Test Group with a few testers.

Under the 'Builds' tab in the aforementioned group when I select the build in the 'Select a Build to Test' dialog I get the following error message in the browser console:

```
Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.testInfo.find(function(t){return t.locale===e.defaultLocale}).feedbackEmail')
```

Anyone have any ideas? 
NOTE: I do have valid feedback email entered within the Test Information page, and have also tried various other emails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK it seems that iTunes connect does not like 0.x versions. Set it to 1.0 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Same problems here.
Not working if I re-submit 1.0.0 version build+1,
and still show loading and the error show in the browser(chrome) console

Comment: Problem fixed, according apple forum(https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/75870), solved by adding 'English US ' in the Test Flight / 'Test Information' !