# iTunes Connect Test Flight External Beta Loading Forever

Tags: app-store-connect

A couple of weeks ago I uploaded an app to iTunes Connect to attempt to beta test it with external users. Unfortunately, whenever I attempt to add a build to my created external tester group and I hit "Next", I am confronted with a loading screen that never goes away. I have left my computer running with this loading screen for multiple days and it still never goes away. I have contacted Apple Developer Support the the engineers have been "looking at it" for 2 weeks now. Does any one know why this could be happening or any possible solutions? Below I attached a picture of the page that has the "Next" button followed by a screenshot of the loading animation that I see after I hit the button. Thank you for the help! [image: This is a picture of the page that I hit next on before a loading icon appears on my screen permanently.]

[image: The page that I see forever after hitting the next button]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem fixed, according apple forum(forums.developer.apple.com/thread/75870), solved by adding 'English US ' in the Test Flight / 'Test Information' !

[iTunes connect - TestFlight - Console Error on Selecting Build for Test Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43362214/itunes-connect-testflight-console-error-on-selecting-build-for-test-group)